# AppCompat action bar size differ from ActionBarSherlock's size

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, material-design, android-appcompat

I've decided to migrate from ActionBarSherlock (ABS) to AppCompat-v7. I ran into a problem. ActionBar became 56dp size instead of 48dp as it was in Holo theme. As I found in AppCompat resources the default action bar size is equal 56dp as in Material design. But I want my action bar looks like action bar in Holo theme. How can I specify necessary size for action bar? Maybe there is AppCompat-v7 with Holo instead of Material?

[image: action bar comparison]

Comment: If you're using appcompat-v7, you get Material theme. There is no Holo styling in appcompat any more, and you will run into numerous difficulties trying to make your app look like Holo. You should migrate your app to Material.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is **normal**.

`Appcompat v21` library enables you to bring the Material designs to older Android platforms.

If you would like to change the height you can use a Toolbar in your layout and set your favorite height.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id=”@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
```

In any case I suggest you to adopt the Material Desing and use the standard dimens.
You can find more info [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use height attribute, actionBarSize if for something else.

```
<item name="android:height">@dimen/bar_height</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

The new AppCompat is meant to implement Material Design, so I encourage you to comply with the guidelines and use the default size. However, if you want to use a non-standard size for your material Action Bar, you can override `actionBarSize` in your theme:

```
<item name="actionBarSize">@dimen/bar_height</item>
```

If you want a true Holo ActionBar, you need to use AppCompat version 20.0.0, which is the last version to support Holo. But then you are stuck and can't use any new version of the support library.